# Vuejs - how to awoid to put numbers in v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have got a left menu, that can show contents depending of the id of the selected menu.

But i got `=== 0` and `=== 1` in the `v-if` and I would like to avoid to put numbers manually there.

```
<template>
  <v-card elevation="2" class="experiences-container">
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex md3 sm12 xs12 class="relative">
        <div class="settings-list"
          :class="switchSetting ? 'open' : ''">
          <v-list>
            <v-list-tile
              v-for="(item, index) in menu"
              :key="index"
              :class="['experience-item', index === idSelectedSetting ? 'active' : '']"
              @click="updateSelectedSetting(index)"
            >
              <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-action v-if="index == idSelectedSetting ? true : false">
                <v-icon>chevron_right</v-icon>
              </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
        </div>

      </v-flex>
      <v-flex md9 sm12 xs12>
          <UserPasswordEdition class="setting-details"
            v-if="idSelectedSetting === 0"
            :class="switchSetting ? 'close' : ''"
          />
          <div
            class="setting-details"
            :class="switchSetting ? 'close' : ''"
            v-if="idSelectedSetting === 1">
            <div class="WIP">Autre menu</div>
          </div>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

--

```
data() {
    return {
        menu: [
            { name: 'Mot de passe' },
            { name: 'Autre menu' }
        ],
      idSelectedSetting: 0,
      switchSetting: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateSelectedSetting(id) {
      this.idSelectedSetting = id;
      this.closeSwitchSetting();
    },
    openSwitchSetting() {
      this.switchSetting = true;
    },
    closeSwitchSetting() {
      this.switchSetting = false;
    }
  }
```

--

I just wanna change the v-if here:

```
<UserPasswordEdition class="setting-details"
            v-if="idSelectedSetting === 0"
            :class="switchSetting ? 'close' : ''"
          />
          <div
            class="setting-details"
            :class="switchSetting ? 'close' : ''"
            v-if="idSelectedSetting === 1">
            <div class="WIP">Autre menu</div>
          </div>
```

I tried a `v-for` but I couldn't make it, or I don't know how to use it in this situation because it shows both content on each menu and I don't want that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with all your options. You'll probably need to use [:is](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to render individual components.

You should also add an `index` on your data and compare it with a `selectedIndex` when rendering.

```
data() {
 return {
  selectedIndex: 0, //default value goes here
  itemsToShow: [
   {
    id: 0,
    component: 'UserPasswordEdition',
   },
   {
    id: 1,
    component: 'OtherComponent'
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

And then update your `template`

```
<template>
  ...
  <v-flex md9 sm12 xs12>
    <component v-for="option in itemsToShow" 
               :key="option.id" 
               :is="option['component']
               v-if="selectedIndex === option.id"
    />
  </v-flex>
</template>
```

Note: this works if you need to pass the same props to all components, otherwise your rendering logic will grow a little more complex.

Edit: added this after @Jer got a warning about not using `v-for` and `v-if` on the same directive.

You can also use a computed property to filter your array

```
computed: {
 filteredItemsToShow() {
   return this.itemsToShow.filter(item => item.id === this.selectedIndex)
  }
}
```

And then use `filteredItemsToShow` when rendering

```
<template>
  ...
  <v-flex md9 sm12 xs12>
    <component v-for="option in filteredItemsToShow" 
               :key="option.id" 
               :is="option['component']
    />
  </v-flex>
</template>
```

Notice the removal of `v-if` as it is baked into the computed property.

Comment: Thanks it work ! but now vscode says : "[vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for]
The 'menu' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'."

Comment: I've updated my answer to avoid using `v-for` and `v-if` on the same node.

Comment: Thanks! i've edited everything, but now it says "this" is undefined on this.itemsToShow.filter (in the computed property ). tried to remove the this but it says itemToshow is undefined. i've got ithe temsToShow array in data of course

Comment: My bad, I wrote it without actually thinking it thru. You can't use fat arrows in computed or methods.

Comment: I tried to put a normal function but it didn't work, it was because i forgot "return" also! thank you very much! 

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your condition to computed property. Example:

```
<template>
  ...
  <v-flex md9 sm12 xs12>
    <UserPasswordEdition class="setting-details"
      v-if="!isSelectedSetting"
      :class="switchSetting ? 'close' : ''"
    />
    <div
      class="setting-details"
      :class="switchSetting ? 'close' : ''"
      v-if="isSelectedSetting"
    >
      <div class="WIP">Autre menu</div>
    </div>
  </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        menu: [
          { name: 'Mot de passe' },
          { name: 'Autre menu' }
        ],
        idSelectedSetting: 0,
        switchSetting: false,
      };
    },
    computed: {
      isSelectedSetting() {
        return this.idSelectedSetting === 1
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't put all of the code, so you didn't know that idSelectedSetting in the data were already changing when we click on a menu. I guess in your situation, i can't put more than 2 menus (i edited my post to show you the code) Thanks !